# MySQL replication allowing duplicate Primary Key entries after replication restart

Tags: mysql, primary-key, database-replication

I have a `MySQL Master`(`v. 5.1.56-ndb-7.1.18-cluster-gpl-log`) - 2 Slaves(both `v. 5.1.51-community`) system setup and has been running for several years. It was originally intended to be a cluster which is why the master has an `ndb` version.

This past weekend, the Master locked up after the kernel complained about a RAM chip error (`"Dazed and confused but trying to continue"` error in /var/log/messages).  I did not personally handle the recovery but the person that did relayed to me that replication was stopped the server restarted and then replication was restarted using the appropriate relay-log values.  I'm assuming he also used skip-errors when the replication restarted. My understanding of skip errors is that it acts like an ignore errors command but it doesn't suspend constraints.

Even if it wasn't done properly, what has ended up happening should not be able to happen. One slave is fine, the other slave has about 20-30 duplicate `Primary Key` entries in a table.  The table is `InnoDB`. I'm not saying that we got the `"1062"` error for duplicate key collisions, we have duplicate records.  This was discovered because reporting was off and when the record was updated to adjust values, the `"UPDATE"` takes effect on one record while the `"SELECT"` reads the other.  I double checked, the `PRIMARY KEY` exists on the Slave structure as well. Has anyone seen this before?

Our planned "fix" is to run a delete command on the Master, that will not delete anything on the Master or the one Slave but since on the second Slave, only one of the records was updated we can uniquely identify it using another column.  This makes sense except for the fact that the duplicate record shouldn't exist in the first place, which makes me worried about doing anything to touch either one of the rows.

Any suggestions? or why this happened in the first place?

Comment: you'd be better off rebuilding the slaves. if the master's gotten desynched from the slaves, it's best to just dump the slaves and start from scratch. otherwise you'd have to compare every record in every table to make sure they're identical, and all table metadata as well (like auto-inc values). But in any case, offtopic. not a programming question. You'd be better off asking on the DBA site.